# Entry Animation does not play again when Animator is disabled then enabled

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an animation I created called "FallingTile" that plays on my object on the Entry phase of the Animator.  The problem is, because I need to change the color of the object throughout my game I need to toggle the Animator on only when it's being used, and then disable it again (this seems to be the only way to be able to change the object's color still).  The first time the object's Animator is enabled the "FallingTile" effect runs smoothly and the Animator is disabled properly.  However if I try to trigger the same object to animate again it will not do so.  I don't believe Entry is only ran the first time the Animator is enabled because I use the same type of system for fading in/out background colors.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
public void FallingTilesAnimation() {
    Anim.enabled = true;
    Invoke ("DisableAnimator", 1.1f);
}

private void DisableAnimator() {
    Anim.enabled = false;
    TileImage.material = null;
}
```

I also tried setting the Animator state back to Idle before disabling it to see if maybe that was the issue but it didn't seem to help.

edit: Probably worth noting my object starts with no material and one is added/manipulated in the FallingTile animation.  It should go back to having no material after the animation ends to "reset" to the pre-animation object.

edit2:  I realized it may be that Entry only runs the first time the Animator is enabled.  For changing background colors I'm changing the active state of the entire object - setting the object to active likely triggers Entry again but enabling the Animator a second time may not?

Comment: you may be better off starting and stopping an animation clip (going from falling anim to idle anim), instead of toggling the entire animator component on and off.

Comment: I can't do that because having the Animator enabled on an object disables it's ability to change color with the Image component, which I need for my game

Comment: Why? The animator can still be active with no clip playing, which should not prevent any other action from occuring. After your entry animation finishes, transition to a blank state with no clip.

Comment: I'm unsure why.  If the Animator is active then my objects won't change color.  This may be due to an active animation running.  Is there a way to play no animation at all instead of playing Idle, or is that the same thing?

Comment: If your Idle animation is not touching any properties, it should be the same as having a blank state with no animation attached.

Comment: Enabling the Animator definitely causes my objects to not change color.  However I tried changing the default Entry state to Idle and then running Anim.Play ("FallingTile"); and that did not even run the animation once, even though the Animator was enabled.

Comment: if you remove the current animator and add a blank one, does it still prevent the color change while enabled?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166050/discussion-between-dulongj-and-ryemoss).

Comment: It looks like by enabling Loop on the animation it will now trigger more than once.  But because the animator is being turned off on a timer the animation is now sometimes stopped slightly too late due to lag, cause the object to be placed incorrectly.